# How to alter a package oracle without deleting the package

Tags: database, oracle, package, alter

I need to add a function to this package without deleting the package? Just add another function.

```
    DROP PACKAGE BANINST1.SB_ENROLLMENT
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BANINST1.sb_enrollment AS
     FUNCTION f_query_all_active_ptrm ()
          RETURN enrollment_ref;
    END sb_enrollment;
    DROP PACKAGE BODY BANINST1.SB_ENROLLMENT
    /


    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY BANINST1.sb_enrollment AS
    FUNCTION f_query_all_active_ptrm ()
          RETURN enrollment_ref;
       BEGIN
       END f_query_all_active_ptrm;
    END sb_enrollment;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't `ALTER` a package to add a new function.  Since you are using `CREATE OR REPLACE`, though, there is no need to `DROP` the package or the package body.  Since a package is a single object, you'd need to replace both the package specification and the package body in its entirety (so you would need to include all the existing functions and procedures).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BANINST1.sb_enrollment 
AS
  FUNCTION f_query_all_active_ptrm ()
    RETURN enrollment_ref;

  FUNCTION new_function_name
    RETURN number;
END sb_enrollment;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY BANINST1.sb_enrollment 
AS
  FUNCTION f_query_all_active_ptrm ()
    RETURN enrollment_ref;
   BEGIN
     <<some implementation>>
   END f_query_all_active_ptrm;

  FUNCTION new_function_name
    RETURN number
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN 1;
  END;
END sb_enrollment;
```